# Rails undefined method in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Link resource (Link as in url's). I have a method in my Links controller to determine whether or not a link that a user enters has the "http://" prefix, and if not, to append that prefix to the URL. Although I defined the method in my Links controller, I am getting an undefined method error.

Here is the relevant portion of my links controller:

```
helper_method :link_formatter

def link_formatter(url)
  prefix = "http://"
  url.include?(prefix)? url : prefix + url
end
```

Here is my links view:

```
<%= link_to link.description, link_formatter(link.url), :target => '_blank' %>
```

The error:

```
undefined method `link_formatter' for #<#<Class:0x007fbd51e2ea08>:0x007fbd5250cfa0>
```

Comment: show the error please.

Comment: The `link_formatter` is a generic method that could be used on any URL, not just `Link` resource. Move it to your `ApplicationHelper`.

Comment: So do you have the helper method defined in helper methods, or is all of it in the controller?

Comment: it should be a helper method

Answer (score 0):

The `link_formatter` is a generic function that can be used by any view in your Rails application. To make it accessible by all your views add it to the `ApplicationHelper` as @Damien Roche said. The application helper is located in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`. You can also generate a new helper by running `rails generate helper HELPER_NAME` on the command line.